# concatenate pandas dataframes with priority replacment of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have data collected from a lineage of instruments with some overlap. I want to merge them to a single pandas data structure in a way where the newest available data for each column take precedence if not NaN, otherwise the older data are retained.

The following code produces the intended output, but involves a lot of code for such a simple task. Additionally, the final step involves identifying duplicated index values, and I am nervous about whether I can rely on the "last" part because df.combine_first(other) reorders the data. Is there a more compact, efficient and/or predictable way to do this?

```
# set up the data
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0.,1.,2.,3.,4,],"y":[0.,1.,2.,3.,np.nan],"t" :[0,1,2,3,4]})   # oldest/lowest priority
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x" : [np.nan,4.1,5.1,6.1],"y":[3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1],"t": [3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x" : [8.2,10.2],"t":[8,10]})
df0.set_index("t",inplace=True)
df1.set_index("t",inplace=True)
df2.set_index("t",inplace=True)

# this concatenates, leaving redundant indices in df0, df1, df2
dfmerge = pd.concat((df0,df1,df2),sort=True)
print("dfmerge, with duplicate rows and interlaced NaN data")
print(dfmerge)

# Now apply, in priority order, each of the original dataframes to fill the original
dfmerge2 = dfmerge.copy()
for ddf in (df2,df1,df0):
    dfmerge2 = dfmerge2.combine_first(ddf)
print("\ndfmerge2, fillable NaNs filled but duplicate indices now reordered")
print(dfmerge2)   # row order has changed unpredictably

# finally, drop duplicate indices
dfmerge3 = dfmerge2.copy()
dfmerge3 = dfmerge3.loc[~dfmerge3.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print ("dfmerge3, final")
print (dfmerge3)
```

The output of which is this:

```
dfmerge, with duplicate rows and interlaced NaN data
       x    y
t            
0    0.0  0.0
1    1.0  1.0
2    2.0  2.0
3    3.0  3.0
4    4.0  NaN
3    NaN  3.1
4    4.1  4.1
5    5.1  5.1
6    6.1  6.1
8    8.2  NaN
10  10.2  NaN

dfmerge2, fillable NaNs filled but duplicate indices now reordered
       x    y
t            
0    0.0  0.0
1    1.0  1.0
2    2.0  2.0
3    3.0  3.0
3    3.0  3.1
4    4.0  4.1
4    4.1  4.1
5    5.1  5.1
6    6.1  6.1
8    8.2  NaN
10  10.2  NaN

dfmerge3, final
       x    y
t            
0    0.0  0.0
1    1.0  1.0
2    2.0  2.0
3    3.0  3.1
4    4.1  4.1
5    5.1  5.1
6    6.1  6.1
8    8.2  NaN
10  10.2  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
s=pd.concat([df0,df1,df2],sort=False)
s[:]=np.sort(s,axis=0)
s=s.dropna(thresh=1)
s
      x    y
t           
0   0.0  0.0
1   1.0  1.0
2   2.0  2.0
3   3.0  3.0
4   4.0  3.1
3   4.1  4.1
4   5.1  5.1
5   6.1  6.1
6   8.2  NaN
8  10.2  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea of using sort to help seems promising, but the fact that this turns out OK seems particular to the example data and even if that isn't the case it alters the index and my index is meaningful (ultimately it will be a timestamp).